# re-arrange string to a palindrome C

Tags: c

```
void MakeItPOLI(char Input[99])
{
    char poli[99]="", ch[2],chV2[2]; // chV2- will be the middle letter(if there is odd number of letters)
    int arr[26]={0},i,j,flag=0; // flag=1 if there is need for middle letter. 
    ch[1]='\0'; chV2[1]='\0';
    for(i=0;i<99;i++) arr[Input[i] - 'a']++;
    for(i=0; i<26;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]%2!=0){arr[i]-=1;chV2[0]=i+'a'; flag=1;}
        for(j=0;j<arr[i]/2;j++){ch[0]=i+'a'; strcat(poli,ch);}
    }
    strrevV2(poli,chV2, flag); 
}
void strrevV2(char poli[99], char chV2[2], int flag){
    int e=strlen(poli),s=0; char revpoli[99]="",temppoli[99]="";
    strcpy(temppoli,poli);
    while (e!=0) revpoli[s++]=temppoli[--e];
    if(flag==1) strcat(poli,chV2); strcat(poli,revpoli);
    printf("This is not a palindrom but it could be\n---> %s\n",poli);

}
```

EDIT-

thanks for the help. it was an assignment from university C class (Im an ee student) the code should take a string and re arrange it to a palindrome. with out adding letters, as some comments here did, [test could never be a palindrome , but zccbbaa should be abczcba] but they helped me learn, so thanks!

i did not had time to fully explain the q. the other day. this is a very small part of a big and annoying assignment. [500 lines of codes, some did closer to 1000, least iv seen is around 500]. above is my code, with the same idea i had, but working! (there is another codes that make sure "input[99]") can be a palindrome- if it has max of one letter thats appeared odd number of times

Comment: What do you expect to happen with `Letters[Input[i]]++;`?

Answer (score 6):

`Letters[Input[i]]` is plain wrong, and it invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) accessing array out of bounds.

As you can see on a [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) values of letters are not from `0` to `25`, as you supposed.

You can do, for example:

```
int index;
for(i=0;i<size;i++)
{
    index = toupper(Input[i]) - 'A';
    if ((index >= 0) && (index < 26))
    {
       Letters[index]++;
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**
If you can assume all input letters and are lower case just

```
Letters[Input[i] - 'a']++;
```

---

**EDIT2**

Moreover your loop

```
for (i = Letters[j]; Letters[j] != 0; i = i - 2)
```

does not take care of i>0: fixed

```
for (i = Letters[j]; (Letters[j] != 0) && (i>=0); i = i - 2)
```

---

**EDIT3**

trying to correct your code without using "too complicated" matters, your code can simply be

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void MakeItPOLI(char Input[99])
{
    int i, size, j;
    size = strlen(Input);

    char Poli[99] = {0};

    for (i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        Poli[i] = Input[i];
    }

    if ((size%2) == 0)
    {
        j=size-1;
    }
    else
    {
        j=size-2;
    }

    do
    {
        Poli[i++] = Input[j];
    }
    while (j-- > 0);

    Poli[i] = '\0';

    printf("This is not a palindrom but it could be: %s\n", Poli);
}

int main()
{
    char test[99] = "test";
    char test2[99] = "testc";
    MakeItPOLI(test);
    MakeItPOLI(test2);
}
```

OUTPUT

```
This is not a palindrom but it could be: testtset
This is not a palindrom but it could be: testctset
```

Comment: thanks! , they are not , but i added 'a'. so it will be from 'a' to 'a'+25 wich is 'z' at least it sopused to be. what is "toupper"?

Comment: @LiadSagi Iìm not getting you. Your array indices starts from 0 to 25: no other chances....

Comment: [toupper](https://linux.die.net/man/3/toupper) converts the letter c to upper case, if possible.

Comment: we should assume all lower case, only ANSCI C string.h, stdio.h libraries, so no toupper.

Comment: Thanks! I'v change it, but the program wont work. its stop in the middle of the run.  nothing shoould not have changed... and it still wont print the right string c gives me the headache sometimes.. C# and Python was better...

Comment: @LiadSagi I edited. Hope it helps. Do not forget to close the question selecting the correct answer.

Comment: Your corrected loop condition discards the first result. Did you mean to use &&?

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Yes. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *makeItPal(char *str)
{
  if (!str || strlen(str) < 2)
    return NULL;

  char *dest = malloc(sizeof(char) * ((strlen(str) * 2) + 1));
  if (!dest)
    exit(0);

  int i = 0, j = 0;
  for (i = 0; str[i]; i++)
    dest[j++] = str[i];

  i -= 2;

  while (i >= 0)
    {
      dest[j] = str[i];
      i--;
      j++;
    }

  dest[j] = 0;
  return dest;
}

int main()
{
  char str[] = "stack";
  char str2[] = "foo";
  char str3[] = "str3";

  char *dest = makeItPal(str);
  char *dest2 = makeItPal(str2);
  char *dest3 = makeItPal(str3);

  printf("%s\n", dest);
  printf("%s\n", dest2);
  printf("%s\n", dest3);
}
```

here is i think a better solution

```
Output : rifzy@rifzy-HP-EliteBook-840-G1:~$ gcc test.c && ./a.out
         stackcats
         fooof
         str3rts
```

Comment: why ? school exercise ? I find it totally stupid to forbid pointers ... but you don't choose. You can edit it and do it without pointers

Comment: C course at the university.. no "unlearned stuff" are allowed until all gruops will do them

Comment: @LiadSagi then try to use the same logic i used but with char arrays instead of char pointers; not really difficult ;)

Comment: Don't give the answer; it's a school assignment. Help, of course, but don't post a full solution. Give guidance....

Comment: @FrankV how am i supposed to know if it's a school exercise or not if he don't say it in his post ?

Comment: @RomMer at the time I read the question which was before there were answers, the OP did note this was a school/homework assignment. Also, the very nature of the question indicates it's a learning exercise.